# Python 3.5 tkinter won't install Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter, python-3.5

Trying to run a script written for Python3.5 on Ubuntu 64 bit.

I'm 99% sure I installed Python3.5 correctly. It lives at /usr/local/bin. But I am getting this error when I try to run my script:

```
import tkinter as tk   # python3

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk

ImportError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

I've tried many of the workarounds on here, but to no avail.

```
apt-get install python3-tk
```

Says it's up to date and

```
update-python-modules -a
```

seems to execute fine, so I really don't know why it's not finding tkinter...

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: I just blew away the VM, so if someone could give me proper steps on installing Python3.5 + tkinter on Ubuntu 64-bit 14.04, that'd be awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: is the `tkinter` module placed within your python directory?

Comment: So it looks like there are two tkinter folders that relate to Python3.5:

1.) /test/Python-3.5.1/Lib/tkinter.

2.) Home/local/lib/python3.5/tkinter.

The /test/ directory is where I actually installed Python3.5 from.

Comment: Ubuntu includes an installation of Python, which does not include Tkinter, because that requires Tcl, which is not included with Ubuntu. If you installed a Python build that is bundled with Tcl, make sure that you are invoking the correct Python install (the one you installed, not the default).